# How Browser Cache Behaves If Local Clock is Not Consistent With Server Clock?

Tags: http, caching

While reading http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html, I found that the caching algorithm is more complex than I thought.

According to RFC2616, HTTP request is sent if response is fresh. and

```
response_is_fresh = (freshness_lifetime > current_age)
```

The **current_age** can be derived from **max-age** or **Expires** header, which both have nothing to do with local clock. However, the calculation of **freshness_lifetime** depends on local clock.

So, if local clock of browser is not consistent with clock at server side. Is it possible that HTTP caching doesn't exempt unnecessary request sent?

Thanks

Comment: Now, I suppose browses just compute current_age as now - "time response is received". It is easy and simple. Anyway, application should not depend its behavior on cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their clocks do not have to be in sync, but the client needs a working clock to be able to determine the age of a cached resource and match that against `max-age`. If `max-age` is not present in the response, a client could calculate it by comparing the **[`Date`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18)** and **[`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21)** headers to each other.

However, if the client were to suffer from extreme clock skew, the cache would break down and resources could get cached incorrectly since their age can not reliably be determined.